# Incorrect Normals from Sphere

Tags: javascript, raytracing

My raytracer is giving some strange results whenever I try to draw the `normals` of my Spheres.

My `Ray`s have an origin `o` and a direction `dir`.

My `Sphere`s have a center `c` and a radius `r`.

I get my circle's radius from the normalized difference between the world space intersection point and the world space center of the sphere that I'm trying to get the normal of:

```
exports.Sphere.prototype.getNormal = function(point) {
   var n = math.normalize(math.subtract(point, this.c));
   return n;
};
```

This point is found from the parabolic line equation after finding `t` from a ray/sphere intersection algorithm (here's the important parts):

```
distProjToSphereSqrt = math.magnitude(math.subtract(projSphereRay, sphere.c));
distToCollisionPoint = Math.sqrt(
        (sphere.r * sphere.r) - (distProjToSphereSqrt * distProjToSphereSqrt));
if (math.magnitude(raySphereDist) > sphere.r) {
   t = (math.magnitude(
           math.subtract(projSphereRay, ray.o)) - distToCollisionPoint);
}
else {
   t = (math.magnitude(
           math.subtract(projSphereRay, ray.o)) + distToCollisionPoint);
}
var point = ray.getPoint(t);
return new math.CollisionRecord(
        t, point,
        math.normalize(math.subtract(point, sphere.c)));
```

I really thought that most of this was going correctly.  However, I think I'm getting the incorrect normal calculation because, while the silhouette of my spheres is drawn correctly, my lighting calculations seem off.  To verify the normal problem, I draw the normals to the screen and get this:

[image: Ray-sphere Normals Raster]

I would *think* that all the normals of all of the spheres would be the exact same.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is a case where writing a simple unit test would quickly verify your math.

Comment: Do you mean parametric line equation?

Comment: How is projSphereRay calculated?